# Licence assignment O365 to Azure AD

Tags: powershell, office365, azure-powershell

I'm here to ask you a question about my code, when I try to give a licence to my user there's an error that told me the user cannot be found.

But If I launch the following one, alone it works.

```
$upn = 't.test6@mytest.fr'
Connect-MsolService
#Get-MsolUser | Where-Object {($_.licenses).AccountSkuId -match "reseller-account:SPB"}
Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $upn
Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $upn -UsageLocation US
Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $upn -AddLicenses "reseller-account:SPB"
```

But the same one, in my code at the end of user creation there it is, it seem that he can't take the string  :

```
Get-MsolUser : User Not Found.  User: t.test5@mytest.fr. Au caractère C:\Users\...\OneDrive - ...\Bureau\AzureAD_user.ps1:47 : 1
+ Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $upn
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Get-MsolUser], MicrosoftOnlineException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.UserNotFoundException,Microsoft.Online.Admini stration.Automation.GetUser

Set-MsolUser : User Not Found.  User: . Au caractère C:\Users\...\OneDrive - ...\Bureau\AzureAD_user.ps1:48 : 1
+ Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $upn -UsageLocation US
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Set-MsolUser], MicrosoftOnlineException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.UserNotFoundException,Microsoft.Online.Admini stration.Automation.SetUser

Set-MsolUserLicense : User Not Found.  User: . Au caractère C:\Users\...\OneDrive - ...\Bureau\AzureAD_user.ps1:49 : 1
+ Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $upn -AddLicenses "reseller-ac ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Set-MsolUserLicense], MicrosoftOnlineException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.UserNotFoundException,Microsoft.Online.Admini stration.Automation.SetUserLicense
```

Any advices ? I'm a begginner and want to give to my users o365 licences right after the user creations. :D

Comment: Could it be a timing issue? i.e. if you create a new user account, it may take a little bit of time (e.g. several seconds) before you can `Get-MsolUser` and find them. Try adding a delay before you try to `Get-MsolUser` and see if that works.

Comment: Works perfectly, I just added a :Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
Thanks to you ! :D

Answer (score 0):

It could be a timing issue.

If you create a new user account, it takes a little bit of time (e.g. it could be several seconds) before you can use `Get-MsolUser` and find them. Try adding a delay before you try to `Get-MsolUser` and see if that works. e.g.

```
New-MsolUser ....

Start-Sleep -Seconds 10

Get-MsolUser ....
```